# UIImage value not being picked up by iPad Mini

Tags: ios, swift

I have multiple `UIImageViews` with different images in them, and I need to create an array that has the names of each of the `UIImages`. I did this by having a switch block for the different images and then appending different string values to an array depending on the image. The app is only for the iPad and my code works fine for all the iPad devices except for the iPad Mini 4 and 5 for some reason. Any help on why this is would be greatly appreciated.

```
for subview in smallView.subviews{
    if let item = subview as? UIImageView{
        switch(item.image!){
            case UIImage(named: "first_image"):
                arrayOfImageNames.append("first_image")
            case UIImage(named: "second_image"):
                arrayOfImageNames.append("second_image")
            default:
                arrayOfImageNames.append("")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange!.... Try to clear driveddata and clean the build and then run the app.

Comment: @MohitMangla Hmm... I deleted the app and restarted my computer but it still appends the default string even when first_image or second_image is the image of the UIImageView

Comment: What do you mean by default string? Can you give some example here?

Comment: @MohitMangla I meant the default in the switch case is to append an empty string "" if none of the case images are the image in the UIImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to compare NSData of images.

```
extension UIImage {

func isEqualToImage(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    let data1: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)!
    let data2: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    return data1.isEqual(data2)
}
}
```